# Error in setting LinqDataSource Where Clause with datetime column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, datetime, where-clause

i want to set the following linqdatasource where clause in code behind.

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="lds" runat="server" ContextTypeName="dcDataContext"
    TableName="vStaff_Currents" OrderBy="Department,DisplayName" >
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

in code behind:

```
Dim filterString As String = ""

Dim AtDate As Date = Nothing

AtDate = Request("PeriodEnd").ToDate

filterString = "xxxxxxxxxxx"

filterString = filterString & "xxxxxxxxxxx"

lds.Where = filterString
```

i want to Insert datetime condition in where clause from querystring `[Request("PeriodEnd")]`

i had tried different command, but it returns error

**Option 1:**

```
filterString = filterString & " and (RenumerationDate <= DateTime.Parse(" & AtDate & "))"
```

**Error:**

*No applicable method 'Parse' exists in type 'DateTime'*

**Option 2:**

```
filterString = filterString & " and (RenumerationDate <= " & AtDate.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy") & " )"
```

**Error:**

**Operator '<=' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime?' and 'Int32'**

How can I add the where clause in code behind ? Thanks

Comment: What is your "RenumerationDate " datatype?

Comment: hi, the datatype is "datetime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
filterString = filterString & " and (RenumerationDate <= DateTime.Parse(""" & AtDate & """))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
filterString = filterString & " and (RenumerationDate <= " & DateTime.Parse(AtDate) & ")"
```

or

```
filterString = filterString & " and (RenumerationDate <= " & Convert.ToDateTime(AtDate) & ")"
```

Comment: thx. but it return error    "Operator '<=' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime?' and 'Int32' "